# How to target html5 main element as a parent node using javascript to remove the main elements children

Tags: javascript, html

Hi as the title say I am wondering how I can target the  tag to use as a parent node  using javascript so I can remove the contents of it (all 's children). Lets start with my html (I want to remove the button)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title></title>


</head>

<body>

    <main>
        <input type="button" id="start" name="startQ" value="Start Quiz">
    </main>
<script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>

</html>
```

now I am kinda lost on how to target that main tag. I know if I change main --> div id=main I could use the js code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("main");
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
```

But id like to use main Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByTagName

Comment: I want to remove the button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to remove main tag

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
```

to remove button

```
var x = document.getElementById("start");
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
```